# FFMPEG - Can i repeat input video to fix screen

Tags: ffmpeg

I want repreat-x input video with output size.

EX :
 
- Input video : 320x720
 
- Output Video : 1280x720
 
- Image Demo : As shown below

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7OOf.png]

What ffmpeg code can do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the stack filters.

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -filter_complex "[0][0][0][0]hstack=4" -c:a copy out.mp4
```